# Convert data from int to string

Tags: reporting-services

If the table is:

### Month

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

I need help how to convert it into

### Month

January

Februari

May

etc...

The data needed to be converted as a expressen code in the reporting designer interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the MonthName function

```
=MonthName(Fields!MonthNum.Value)
```